80s movie about siblings who band together to create a calendar
It was in the 80s, probably around or before 1985, with a group of siblings, all different that hate each other, and their dad gets tired of their ways and kicks them all out of their rich house, and makes them live in one of his properties.
They aren't used to the poor life, but eventually discover their individual talents and create a calendar together using costuming skills, painting skills, and photography skills. 
Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

I'm pretty sure this is Where the Heart Is, from 1990.
It starred Dabney Coleman as a patriarch whose children ridicule him for being mean, so he dumps them off at one of the buildings he was going to destroy. They end up banding together and using their unique talents to create a calendar. 
It fits all of your description, except for the year.

YES!!! That's it!! Thank you! It's been driving me crazy for years! No wonder I couldn't find it. My memory insisted that the clothes were very 1980s, so I assumed that's when it was made. Thanks so much!

I was pretty surprised myself to discover it was from 1990, as I was thinking it was mid-80s as well. Maybe they just took awhile to release it after filming? :)

I think you may be right, that this one sat "in the can" for years before being released. It may have even gone straight to video. I have seen it, it's not great, but stars Crispin Glover, so there's that.
